# python unittest prepare test data

Tags: python-3.x, automated-tests, python-unittest, fixtures

I have a parent class for all my tests, which inherited from the unittest.TestCase. It contains a lots of global variables, and a bunch of custom functions for creation and deletion users and other entities.

```
class AutoTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def vars(self):
       self.api = "http://"
       self.auth = HTTPBasicauth("arr", "yarrr")

    def new_user(self):
        requests.post(url, json, auth)
        return response
    """"and so on"""
```

The problem is that I need to prepare test data for test suites and it should be prepared once for all tests in suite (i.e test class). 
As far as I understand, for such cases a `setUpClass` is used, but it's used only as class method, so all defined in parent class ustom functions, which is absolutely crucial for test data preparing become uncallable from it because all of them are instance methods and have "self" positional argument.

```
class TestSomeStuff(AutoTests):

    def setUpClass(cls):
        *and here is the problem, because none of the AutoTest class functions are available*
```

Will appreciate any help/advices.

Comment: Use pytest: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/  **MUCH MUCH** Better....

Comment: @StephenRauch Agreed. But have to work w/ unittest so far

Answer (score 1):

Call the parent class's `setUpClass` method with `super()`. Also you should always decorate `setUpClass` with `@classmethod`.

```
class TestSomeStuff(AutoTests):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(TestSomeStuff, cls).setUpClass()
```

Comment: Yes, I know about decorator and super(). Main problem is that run setUp just once and maintain access to parrent class functions and variables, which have "self" positional argument